# How can I automate Winforms in .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi, vb6, controls

I want to get the ControlName of .NET properties in VB6 code, just like described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996405.aspx). But unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I always got 0 for bufferMem.

```
        bufferMem = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, 0, size, 
        MEM_RESERVE Or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)
        If bufferMem = 0 Then
            Error Err, "VirtualAllocEx API Failed"
        End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the size beforehand?

```
size = 65536
```